# Is it possible to implement a WeakEventManager for UIElement.LayoutUpdated?

Tags: c#, wpf, weak-events, weakeventmanager

I have an application that consumes LayoutUpdated-events and need to register them weak. Here is the problem, I got stuck on, during  implementation of the WeakEventManager

```
internal class WeakLayoutUpdatedManager : WeakEventManager
{
    [..]

    private void OnLayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // NOTE: received sender is always null (by design of LayoutUpdated) 
        base.DeliverEvent(sender, e);
    }
}
```

That's what happens:

1. we always receive null as sender (by design of LayoutUpdated)
2. that null gets passed into DeliverEvent
3. DeliverEvent can not lookup the correct ListenerList, because it needs a sender != null as key

the failing lookup in [WPF: WeakEventManager // DeliverEvent // Line: 359](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/WeakEventManager.cs,ba3d8e4bfbca1992)

```
object sourceKey = (sender != null) ? sender : StaticSource;
list = (ListenerList)Table[this, sourceKey];
```

**My question is**: is there a way to weak-register to LayoutUpdated event?

I'm not interested in the sender-parameter, so it's ok to me that LayoutUpdated always delivers null (my actual implemention with regular "+=" works). But the WeakEventManager base-class relies on the sender-parameter to keep track of the ListenerLists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have found yourself, `null` sender breaks `WeakEventManager` into thinking that this is a static event, which basically makes it incompatible with `LayoutUpdated`. Since `WeakEventManager.DeliverEvent` is non-virtual, you cannot really "fix" it.

So I think your option would be to use a third-party [weak event manager](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=weak%20event%20manager), or write one yourself, which shouldn't be that difficult (unless you need a generic solution).

The idea is to break a hard reference between the event source (`UIElement`) and the event subscriber (`Delegate.Target`), which may be achieved by using a mediator class with weak references to the event handler and its target.

Here is a quick-and-dirty example that would work with events of type `EventHandler`:

```
public class WeakEventListener<TSender>
{
    private readonly EventHandler _handler;
    private readonly EventInfo _event;
    private readonly WeakReference<object> _target;

    // Helps to keep original EventHandler alive as long as its target isn't GCed.
    private readonly ConditionalWeakTable<object, EventHandler> _targetHandler =
        new ConditionalWeakTable<object, EventHandler>();

    public WeakEventListener(string eventName, EventHandler handler)
    {
        _handler = new EventHandler(DeliverEvent);
        _event = typeof(TSender).GetEvent(eventName);
        _target = new WeakReference<object>(handler.Target);
        _targetHandler.Add(handler.Target, handler);
    }

    public void Add(TSender source) => _event.AddEventHandler(source, _handler);

    public void Remove(TSender source) => _event.RemoveEventHandler(source, _handler);

    private void DeliverEvent(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (_target.TryGetTarget(out object target) &&
            _targetHandler.TryGetValue(target, out EventHandler handler))
        {
            handler(sender, args);
        }
    }
}
```

Which may be used as follows:

```
var listener = new WeakEventListener<UIElement>(nameof(LayoutUpdated), OnLayoutUpdated);
listener.Add(uiElement);
```